# Execute jsp web app with tomcat server + eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Im trying to execute a web app a friend did last year so I can take advantadge of it so I dont have to make mine from the beggining.

I installed everything I need to execute a simple jsp web app which gets my browser version and no problem with the tomcat server, but when I try to execute my friend's web app, Eclipse says "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start."

This is my friends web app, in case you can execute it, could you help me to find the problem??

https://mega.nz/#!R8NhSIBZ!w0swqlT9ewx1h8jCgf8XqhVt4Dff43xVAxX29SdZCXo

Comment: Perhaps this is happening because version mismatch if you configure perfectly. Otherwise check another version of tomcat.

Comment: @Alejandro this project is not fully configured. It is better to start a new one.

Comment: @SumeshTG how is that possible?
For example, I tried to open one I found in the internet

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9lKQZ972ibLT29uem5wd1U1QVk/edit

as this guy explained in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUzbICL38ew

But get another error :/

Comment: @AlejandroCorp  Please Refer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/ study step by step.